# Using @Before aspect on @Controller methods with Spring doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have a web-app using Spring 3, where controllers are annotated with @Controller. The public methods of the controllers are annotated with @RequestMapping. This works perfectly fine.

Now I want to do a check before invoking any of the public methods in the controllers. I've created a @Before aspect using a Pointcut expression that selects all controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping. I've registered the aspect using

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="myAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

The problem is that when I've started the application and do a request for some URL handled by one of my controllers, I get the following error-message:

**"No adapter for handler XXX: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?"**

So the controllers don't work anymore. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sean Patrick Floyd is right. There is an other way: switching form Spring Proxy AOP to CGILib.

From the Spring Reference:

> It is possible to force the use of
>   CGLIB, in those (hopefully rare) cases
>   where you need to advise a method that
>   is not declared on an interface, or
>   where you need to pass a proxied
>   object to a method as a concrete type.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-autoproxy-force-CGLIB

> To force the use of CGLIB proxies set
>   the value of the proxy-target-class
>   attribute of the `<aop:config>`
>   element to true: `<aop:config
>   proxy-target-class="true">`
>
> *To force CGLIB proxying when using the @AspectJ autoproxy support, set
>   the 'proxy-target-class' attribute of
>   the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` element
>   to true: `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy
>   proxy-target-class="true"/>`*

*BTW: I recommend to use AspectJ instead or Spring Proxy CGILib AOP.*/

Answer (score 4):

> **Note**
>    When using controller interfaces
>   (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to
>   consistently **put all your mapping
>   annotations** - such as `@RequestMapping`
>   and `@SessionAttributes` - **on the
>   controller interface** rather than on
>   the implementation class.

**Source:** [Spring Reference > Web MVC Framework > Implementing Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Comment: The controller (implementation) classes does not implement any interface, they are only annotated with @Controller.