# Wrapper class using annotation in Spring

Tags: spring, controller, annotations, radix

Is it possible to have a base wrapper class that wraps all my controllers in Spring if I'm using annotations? Basically on all the pages I need to do some checks before displaying the HTML and also include some configurations such as BASE_URL of the site, etc.

I know I can use Spring security to verify a user and their logged in status/permissions to see a page, but then I also need to set variables depending on their permissions levels and such. So is there a way to have a base setup for each page without having to add the same code within each method?

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578354/using-before-aspect-on-controller-methods-with-spring-doesnt-work)

Comment: I cannot for the life of me get the @Before to work. Are there any other possible solutions that don't require so much work to do something seemingly simple?

Answer (score 0):

I would either do this using AOP or (which is more in line with Spring MVC), a [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html), which is the Spring analogue to a servlet filter.